# Error installing laravel 5 app with refering db in AppServiceProvider.php boot

Tags: laravel-5, installation

In laravel 5.8 app I need tofill config values from databse setting and for this I do in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :

```
public function boot()
{
    $request= request();
    if ( \Schema::hasTable(with( new Settings)->getTable() ) ) {
        $settingsArray = Settings::getSettingsList(['site_name', 'site_heading', 'noreply_email'], -1, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        $site_name     = !empty($settingsArray['site_name']) ? $settingsArray['site_name'] : '';
        $site_heading  = !empty($settingsArray['site_heading']) ? $settingsArray['site_heading'] : '';
        $noreply_email = !empty($settingsArray['noreply_email']) ? $settingsArray['noreply_email'] : '';

        config(['feed.feeds.main.title' => htmlspecialchars_decode($site_name . ' : ' . $site_heading)]);
        config(['mail.from.name' => htmlspecialchars_decode($site_name . ' support')]);
        config(['mail.from.address' => htmlspecialchars_decode($noreply_email)]);
    }
```

It works ok, but not when I install my app on server, it looks like that there is reference to boot method above
while running

```
composer install
```

and I got database error, as I have no .env file yet.
If to comment the code above all installation works ok.
If there is some proper way for additive checking, like if key was generated here?

Thanks!

Comment: I still search for a decision. Is there is a better way to fill config values from databse setting, not in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php  ?